# Preparation for Exam, Binary Search Tree Deletion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have an exam tomorrow morning and I have some questions about some code on practice exams. I am given code that I need to identify errors for and describe what happens at runtime.

Binary search tree algorithm
The deletion cases for no child, left child only, and right child only are correct, the one that needs to be corrected and described is the left and right child exist. 
This code is to tactically remove a single node in a BST

```
  /* find the immediate successor */
Tree * su = root -> right ; /* su must not be NULL */
while (( su -> left ) != NULL )
{
su = su -> left ;
}
/* su is root ’ s immediate successor */
/* swap their values */

root -> value = su -> value ;
//Error here, su is not updated to the new value.

/* delete the successor */
root -> right = Tree_delete ( root , val );
//Error here, the Tree_delete call should be root->right, not root. 
return root;
```

I identified the errors, but can someone describe what happens at runtime, and if there is a memory leak?

Comment: You might have climbed several steps in the `while` loop but only delete one element. Does `Tree_delete` go through all elements below it and free them? Otherwise you have a leak there.

Comment: I forgot that delete/destroy convention used in our class is not universal. This code is meant to delete a single node from a BST.

Comment: Just remember that delete is the same as `insert` or `find`, but delete involves a little more book-keeping

Comment: I think you should use this kind of function declaration: Tree_delete( node* &root, Type val)

Comment: Thanks everyone...can anyone else tell me if I have a memory leak or a segfault? I have trouble figuring out what the treedelete(root,val) call does instead of root->right